# PendingIntent and AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-alarms

I'm trying to broadcast after 20 seconds and receive the broadcast with an extended receiver `ExtendedReceiver`.

Here is my function that creates an alarm and sets the `PendingIntent` to go off after 20 seconds:

```
public void alert() {
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ExtendedReceiver.class);
    int _uid = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _uid, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

    Log.i("Title", "Alarm has been set");
}
```

Here is the ExtendedReceiver class:

```
public class ExtendedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Title", "Broadcast received");
    }
}
```

I get my first log message: `Alarm has been set` but I don't get my second log message. I'm unsure where the problem lies (first day on Android)

Comment: Did you register your ExtendedReceiver in your Manifest.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i may this is what i always do.

change your

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _uid, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

to

```
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _uid, new Intent(EXTENDED_RECEIVER_ACTION), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

and important: Register your `ExtendedReceiver` like this:

```
...
registerReceiver(new ExtendedReceiver() , new IntentFilter(EXTENDED_RECEIVER_ACTION));
```

PS: EXTENDED_RECEIVER_ACTION is a String and dont forget to unregister your receiver.

further docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

hope it helps :)